# UIScrollView Indicator is stretched

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, indicator, stretched

I have a paginated UIScrollView with several UIImageViews inside for horizontal scrolling. All works as expected, but there is one strange thing about the horizontal scroll indicator: it looks as if it were stretched to the height of the whole view.

Imagine a horizontal scrollindicator with a height of the whole screen, moving as expected, but - of course - too large. The black bar (the stretched indicator) behaves normally - apart from the wrong display. It looks as if any UIView gets resized after adding it to the scrollview.

Changing the UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle does not have any effect. I could switch off the indicators what wouldn't be very userfriendly.

Does anybody encountered something similar? And what else could be checked?

Comment: I've found the answer myself: When I set the "shows-horizontal-scrollers"-property in IB, the scrollindicator gets stretched. But if set by code, it works as expected: `scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;`